# XmlSerializer - Present an array of items

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have an XML File that looks like this :

```
<ROOT><DOC> ... </DOC><DOC> ... </DOC><DOC> ... </DOC></ROOT>
```

I want to put all the DOC in an array.
How do I do that in C# (XmlSerializer) ?

Comment: Yes you can do it with XmlSerializer.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: This link doesn't help me due to the fact that the array is in Cars.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on the framework version. I have .net v4 and would use the following class with XmlSerializer.

Thanks to @Reniuz for the hint of the error. Here is a full working example:

```
public class Document
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("ROOT")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("DOC")]
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Using this code to load:

```
string data = "<ROOT><DOC Value=\"adhfjasdhf\"></DOC><DOC Value=\"asldfhalsdh\"></DOC></ROOT>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(data))
{
    Root root = serializer.Deserialize(sr) as Root;
}
```

Keep attantion that the tags are case sensitive.

Comment: XmlElement can be applied for fields and properties. You'll get error. For Root class use XmlRoot attribute

Comment: But XmlRoot doesn't help me because my array is empty.

Comment: At the end use

    Document[] documents = root.Documents.ToArray();

to get the array.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you need a string that contains your XML, a StringReader to read the string, an XMLReader to read the feed from the StringReader and an XDocument to store the feed from the XMLReader. This can be done in a single line of code, like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load (XmlReader.Create (new StringReader (xmlString)));
```

The xmlString is the path (and name) of the file you're reading. You should use a List to store the data you'll get (unless it's a set number, then you can just use a string[]).

```
List<string> docList = new List<string>();
```

Then it's a matter of using a foreach loop to go through the XML elements and adding them to your list:

```
foreach (var element in xDoc.Descendants("ROOT"))
{
    string doc = element.Element ("DOC").Value;
    docList.Add (doc);
}
```

to make it an array, use:

```
docList.ToArray();
```

I hope this helps! Good luck.

Comment: Okay. What if you try this:

    foreach (var element in xDoc.Element ("DOC").Value)
    {
        docList.Add (xDoc.Element ("DOC").Value);
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer, based on **Magicbjorn** answer :

First of all, i'm getting my string from a StreamReader.

```
    using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader("FilePath.xml"))
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(read));
        List<string> docList = new List<string>();

        var root = xDoc.Element("ROOT");
        foreach (var element in root.Elements("DOC"))
        {
            string s = element.Value;
            docList.Add(s);
        }
    }
```